# Невозможно неявно преобразовать тип «строка» в «байт»

Tags: c#, unity3d

мне нужно сделать так чтобы строка переобразовалась в тип байт

```
public Text playersCount;

    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = playersCount.text;
    }
```

Comment: Зачем? Так это не делают

Comment: мне нужно либо из скрипта на объекте брать значение переменной, либо из текста, но не то не другое у меня не получается

Comment: `byte.Parse(playersCount.text);`

Answer (score 0):

Правильно делать так: иметь в классе свойство/поле с необходимым типом. И вот значение из этого свойства/поля как-либо передавать куда-либо, а также и рендерить на UI  поверхности

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CreateRoom()
{
    roomOptions.MaxPlayers = Convert.ToByte(playersCount.text);
}
```

Код я не тестил если что